# How to use Matlab (for/while/if)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

[image]

I drew lines at 100,100,20 intervals as shown in the picture.
How do I create code using (for) or (while)? Please let me know.

```
xline(100,'b-');
xline(200,'b-');
xline(220,'b-');
xline(320,'b-');
xline(420,'b-');
xline(440,'b-');
xline(540,'b-');
```

Answer (score 1):

It it's not a constant spacing between x coordinates of your line you'll have to define  a matrix then call for it's element :

```
x_matrix = [100 200 220 320 420 440 540];
for i = 1:length(x_matrix)
xline(x_matrix(i),'b-');
end
```

**PS:** I wouldn't recommend to use plot function in a `while` loop. If the while loop is executed too much times or even if matlab is stuck in it, your computer won't like...

Comment: a `for` loop executing the same number of *too much times*  as that of `while` loop is not any better.